# Hashing problems using a wrapper class around NSUUID as the key

Tags: swift, dictionary, key, lldb

** REWRITE **

OK, it turns out I'm really asking a different question. I understand about hashValue and ==, so that's not relevant.

I would like my wrapper class `BUUID` to "do the right thing" and act just like NSUUID's act in a Dictionary.

See below, where they don't.

```
import Foundation
class BUUID: NSObject {
    init?(str: String) {
        if let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: str) {
            _realUUID = uuid
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    override init() {
        _realUUID = NSUUID()
    }

    private var _realUUID: NSUUID

    override var description: String { get { return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
    override var hashValue: Int { get { return _realUUID.hashValue } }
    var UUIDString: String { get { print("WARNING Use description or .str instead"); return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
    var str: String { get { return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
}
func ==(lhs: BUUID, rhs: BUUID) -> Bool { return lhs._realUUID == rhs._realUUID }

let a = BUUID()
let b = BUUID(str: a.str)!
print("a: \(a)\nb: \(b)")
print("a === b: \(a === b)")
print("a == b: \(a == b)")

var d = [a: "Hi"]
print("\(d[a]) \(d[b])")


let nA = NSUUID()
let nB = NSUUID(UUIDString: nA.UUIDString)!
print("na: \(nA)\nnB: \(nB)")
print("nA === nB: \(nA === nB)")
print("nA == nB: \(nA == nB)")

var nD = [nA: "Hi"]
print("\(nD[nA]) \(nD[nB])")
```

Results. Note that I can look up using NSUUID `nB` and get back what I put under `nA`. Not so with my `BUUID`.

```
a: 9DE6FE91-D4B5-4A6B-B912-5AAF34DB41C8
b: 9DE6FE91-D4B5-4A6B-B912-5AAF34DB41C8
a === b: false
a == b: true
Optional("Hi") nil

nA: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fa193c39500> BB9F9851-93CF-4263-B98A-5015810E4286
nB: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fa193c37dd0> BB9F9851-93CF-4263-B98A-5015810E4286
nA === nB: false 
nA == nB: true
Optional("Hi") Optional("Hi")
```

Comment: The hash value need not be unique. The only requirement is that different elements have different hashes.

Comment: Different keys can have identical hashes, but equality operation should return false for those keys. I have almost prepared an illustrating example. Let me post it.

Comment: That's definitely not good to have all keys with the same hash. In this case we are getting that worst case when search element complexity fells down to O(n) (exhaustive search). But it will work.

Comment: Rewrote to clarify. Different question, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheriting from NSObject also assumes *isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool* method overloading:

```
import Foundation
class BUUID: NSObject {
    init?(str: String) {
        if let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: str) {
            _realUUID = uuid
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    override init() {
        _realUUID = NSUUID()
    }

    private var _realUUID: NSUUID

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let buuid = object as? BUUID else {
            return false
        }

        return buuid._realUUID == _realUUID
    }
    override var description: String { get { return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
    override var hashValue: Int { get { return _realUUID.hashValue } }
    var UUIDString: String { get { print("WARNING Use description or .str instead"); return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
    var str: String { get { return _realUUID.UUIDString } }
}
func ==(lhs: BUUID, rhs: BUUID) -> Bool { return lhs._realUUID == rhs._realUUID }

let a = BUUID()
let b = BUUID(str: a.str)!
print("a: \(a)\nb: \(b)")
print("a === b: \(a === b)")
print("a == b: \(a == b)")

var d = [a: "Hi"]
print("\(d[a]) \(d[b])")


let nA = NSUUID()
let nB = NSUUID(UUIDString: nA.UUIDString)!
print("na: \(nA)\nnB: \(nB)")
print("nA === nB: \(nA === nB)")
print("nA == nB: \(nA == nB)")

var nD = [nA: "Hi"]
print("\(nD[nA]) \(nD[nB])")
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help with this issue. Objective-C can be a heavy legacy when viewed against Swift being billed as a fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to *not* make BUUID inherit from NSObject, which undercuts the Swiftiness of overriding `==`.

So:

```
extension BUUID: Hashable {}
class BUUID: CustomStringConvertible {
    // take away all 'override' keywords, nothing to override
    // otherwise same as above
}
```

Interesting!

Comment: If you inherit from NSObject you need to overload following: func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is relevant to initially asked question: Why that's possible to get two key-value pairs with identical key's hashes in a dictionary**

This example illustrates that keys in Dictionary can have identical hashes, but equality operation should return false for different keys:

```
func ==(lhs: FooKey, rhs: FooKey) -> Bool {

    return unsafeAddressOf(lhs) == unsafeAddressOf(rhs)
}

class FooKey: Hashable, Equatable {

    var hashValue: Int {

        get {
            return 123
        }
    }
}

var d = Dictionary<FooKey, String>()

let key1 = FooKey()
let key2 = FooKey()

d[key1] = "value1"
d[key2] = "value2"
```

Output

```
[FooKey: "value1", FooKey: "value2"]
```

That's definitely not good to have all keys with the same hash. In this case we are getting that worst case when search element complexity fells down to O(n) (exhaustive search). But it will work.